# woocommerce_available_variation filter no longer working after Woocommerce 3 update

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

A few custom codes I've written for woocommerce aren't working properly after updating to woocommerce 3. In this particular case, it's the woocommerce_available_variation filter. I used it to dynamically insert product variation descriptions based on the product attributes.

As of now I am getting this error message:

**Catchable fatal error: Object of class WC_Product_Download could not be converted to string in /home/silent48/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-product-functions.php on line 376**

What would I need to do to the below code to make it compliant with 3.0?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'change_variation_descriptions');
function change_variation_descriptions( $descriptions) {


global $post, $woocommerce;


    $basicmp3des = '<div class="licensedetails">
                    <li>-Delivered in mp3 format instantly after purchase</li>
                    <li>-Synchronization rights are granted</li>
                    <li>-One commercial use is permitted (ie: mixtape, album, etc)</li>
                    <li>-You may distribute up to 5000 profitable units</li>
                    <li>-Includes non-exclusive contract agreement (e-signed at checkout)</li>
                    <li>-Send me a quote to inquire about Exclusive License purchase!</li>
                    </div>';    
    

    

        
     foreach ( $descriptions as $description ) {
        $variation =  wc_get_formatted_variation($description, true );
                    
            
            if (strpos($variation, 'Basic License') !== false && strpos($variation, 'mp3') !== false ) {
                    $descriptions['variation_description'] = $basicmp3des;
            }
            
     }
     
            return $descriptions;     
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `woocommerce_available_variation` has always been an array and not an array of variation objects, so running a `foreach()` and expecting those to be variation is likely causing an error. What does the "basic license" and "mp3" refer too? Are those product attributes? I may be simpler to filter the description directly, but I would need to know how to conditionally add your text to the desired variations.

Comment: Hi helgatheviking. That's the thing, it was all working fine in woocommerce 2.x. And yeah, I'm selling music files by file format and license type. The original code was a lot longer, but I shortened it to show only one description and one variation combo. In full, I have 5 license types and 2 file formats as attributes. I was pretty sure there was a more proper way to do this, but it was the first method I got working, so I never bothered to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two approaches..... I'm not at home so can't test them right now. First, we can try updating what you have to suit the structure of the data array being passed. In both cases, I'm trying to check if the variation has the correct attribute assigned, but that's the part I can't fully test so the condition may not be cut/paste ready. If it doesn't work, you can take a look at `var_dump( $attributes );` or if you have error logging enabled `error_log( json_encode( $attributes ) )` to see what the attribute key/value pairs really are.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'change_variation_descriptions', 10, 3 );
function change_variation_descriptions( $data, $product, $variation ) {

    // Returns array of attribute name value pairs. Keys are prefixed with attribute_, as stored.
    $attributes = $variation->get_attributes();

    if( isset( $attributes['pa_license-options'] && 'basic-license' == $attributes['pa_license-options'] && isset( $attributes['pa_delivery-format'] ) && 'mp3' == $attributes['pa_delivery-format'] ) ) {
        $data['variation_description'] = '<div class="licensedetails">
                    <li>-Delivered in mp3 format instantly after purchase</li>
                    <li>-Synchronization rights are granted</li>
                    <li>-One commercial use is permitted (ie: mixtape, album, etc)</li>
                    <li>-You may distribute up to 5000 profitable units</li>
                    <li>-Includes non-exclusive contract agreement (e-signed at checkout)</li>
                    <li>-Send me a quote to inquire about Exclusive License purchase!</li>
                    </div>';    

    }

    return $data;     
}
```

And next, I think we can just filter the variation description all the time:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_description', 'kia_filter_description', 10, 2 );
function kia_filter_description( $desc, $product ) {
    if( $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
        // Returns array of attribute name value pairs. Keys are prefixed with attribute_, as stored.
        $attributes = $product->get_attributes();

        if( isset( $attributes['pa_license-options'] && 'basic-license' == $attributes['pa_license-options'] && isset( $attributes['pa_delivery-format'] ) && 'mp3' == $attributes['pa_delivery-format'] ) ) {
            $desc .= '<div class="licensedetails">
                    <li>-Delivered in mp3 format instantly after purchase</li>
                    <li>-Synchronization rights are granted</li>
                    <li>-One commercial use is permitted (ie: mixtape, album, etc)</li>
                    <li>-You may distribute up to 5000 profitable units</li>
                    <li>-Includes non-exclusive contract agreement (e-signed at checkout)</li>
                    <li>-Send me a quote to inquire about Exclusive License purchase!</li>
                    </div>';    
        }

    }
    return $desc;
}
```

**EDIT** Code updated to use attribute and term slugs matching the OP's setup.

Comment: Thanks, I've been tinkering with the first option. I managed to get so far as successfully displaying the description if the variation has an attribute set by correcting the attribute slug names. **$attributes['attribute_license']** changed to **$attributes['pa_license-options']**, and **$attributes['attribute_format']** to **$attributes['pa_delivery-format']**. All that remains is figuring out how to check for specific attributes. The **'Basic License' == $attributes['pa_delivery-format']** method doesn't seem to be working, unfortunately.

Comment: Are your attributes a taxonomy? You  may need to use the term slug (which could be 'basic-license' instead of the term name 'Basic License'. I'm not sure on that point.

Comment: Bingo! I changed the basic license attribute title to it's slug format, and it works. I don't know why I didn't think of that lol. Thanks Helga! I updated your answer with the proper slugs and marked it as the chosen answer.